# How to stop changing routes in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

I am new to angular. I am trying to stop navigation to the index page if the user is already logged in. That means I use a cookie by applying the following code.

```
app.run(['$rootScope', 'authService', '$location','$cookieStore', function($rootScope, authService, $location, $cookieStore){
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(evt, next){
        var cookie = $cookieStore.get('AuthorizationHeader');

        if(next == 'http://localhost:3000/#/' && cookie){
             evt.preventDefault();
        }

        if(cookie){
        if(authService.AccessPrivilegesAuth()){
            if(!authService.AccessPrivilegesAdmin(next.access_level)){
                $location.path('categories');
            }

        }else if(authService.AccessPrivilegesAuth()== false){
            $location.path('/');
        }
        }else{
            $location.path('/');
        }
    })
}]);
```

in that part.

```
  if(next == 'http://localhost:3000/#/' && cookie){
                 evt.preventDefault();
            }
```

I am testing if the next route is the index and if the user have a cookie then I stop redirecting however that route changes to `http://localhost:3000/#/` which means it didn't work however the UI does not change it does not even load. What if i removed `evt.preventDefault();` and called `$location.path('categories');`

Comment: Have you checked to see what location is in next and also that the cookie has been returned?

Comment: yes the if statement is valid i can see it in the debug mode